# How to find Maximize of $(m^2 + n^2)/(5 - m n)$ where $m$, $n$ and $(m^2 + n^2)/(5 + m n)$ are integer numbers?

Tags: maximize

I am trying to find Maximize of the expression $(m^2 + n^2)/(5 - m n)$ where $m$, $n$ and $(m^2 + n^2)/(5 - m n)$ are integer numbers. I tried

```
Maximize[{(n^2 + m^2)/(m n - 5), 1 <= n <= 100, 1 <= m <= 100, 
  m > n, {m, n, (n^2 + m^2)/(m n - 5)} \[Element] 
   PositiveIntegers}, {m, n}]
```

I can not get the answer. How can I get it?

Comment: I tried. I want $(n^2 + m^2)/(5 + m n)$ is also an integer number.

Comment: Why your code is `(m n - 5)`? Do you mean `Maximize[{k, (n^2 + m^2) == k*(5 + m n), 1 <= n < m <= 100}, {m, n, 
  k}, PositiveIntegers]`.

Comment: @cvgmt I am sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all solutions:

```
A = SolveValues[{s == (n^2 + m^2)/(m n - 5), n < m <= 100},
                {m, n, s}, PositiveIntegers]
(*    {{3, 2, 13}, {6, 1, 37}, {7, 1, 25}, {18, 1, 25},
       {23, 2, 13}, {31, 1, 37}, {37, 3, 13}}              *)
```

Find the ones that maximize `s`:

```
MaximalBy[A, Last]
(*    {{6, 1, 37}, {31, 1, 37}}    *)
```

Same but faster:

```
f = # . #/(Times @@ # - 5) &;

MaximalBy[Select[Tuples[Range[10^4], 2],
                 OrderedQ[#] && IntegerQ[f[#]] &],
          f]
(*    {{1, 6}, {1, 31}, {6, 221}, {31, 1146}, {221, 8171}}    *)
```

Answer (score 3):

- The original title and the code does not coincide. Maybe

```
Maximize[{k, (n^2 + m^2) == k*(m n - 5), 1 <= n < m <= 100}, {m, n, 
  k}, PositiveIntegers]
```

Or

```
Maximize[{k, (n^2 + m^2) == k*(m n + 5), 1 <= n < m <= 100}, {m, n, 
  k}, PositiveIntegers]
```

- Even as the title instead of the code in the question,the`Maximize` still work.

```
Maximize[{(n^2 + m^2)/(m*n - 5), (n^2 + m^2) == k*(m n + 5), 
  1 <= n < m <= 100}, {m, n, k}, PositiveIntegers]
```

> `{221/8, {m -> 21, n -> 1, k -> 17}}`.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `Maximize` nor `NMaximtze` works with `(n^2 + m^2)/(m n + 5)} \[Element]  PositiveIntegers`. The following does the job.

```
NMaximize[{(n^2 + m^2)/(m n - 5), 1 <= n <= 100, 1 <= m <= 100, m > n,
s == (n^2 + m^2)/(m *n + 5), {m, n, s} \[Element] 
PositiveIntegers}, {m, n, s}]
```

> `{27.625, {m -> 21, n -> 1, s -> 17}}`